# ScrollViewReader, how to read the current row?

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, scrollviewreader

I'm looking for a tidy way to identify the current visible top row from a ScrollView.  I would like the NavigationTitle to display the current row number.
Is there a way to do it with ScrollViewReader or must I do something with GeometryReader?  In the code below I would like myRowNumber to update as the user scrolls up and down. Thanks in advance.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let myArray: [Int] = [Int](1...100)
    @State private var myRowNumber: Int = 50
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack{
                    ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                        ForEach(myArray, id: \.self) { index in
                            Text("Row \(index)").id(index).font(.title)
                        }
                        .onAppear {
                            proxy.scrollTo(50, anchor: .top)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Current row = \(myRowNumber)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### UPDATE

If your deployment target is iOS 17 (or macOS 14, etc.) or later, you can use the [`scrollPosition(id:)` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/scrollposition(id:)) to track the top visible row of the scroll view.

### ORIGINAL

So you want something like this:

[image: A scroll view showing number rows. Row 50 is at the top. The title above the scroll view says "Current row = 50". I scroll the view and the title changes in real time to always say the row number of the top visible row.]

SwiftUI doesn't offer a direct way to read the top row, so we have to compute it using other tools.

We need to know each row's position relative to the top of the scroll view. That means two things: getting an [`Anchor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anchor#) for each row, and computing the y coordinate of that `Anchor` relative to the top of the `ScrollView`.

We can collect the `Anchor`s using the [`anchorPreference`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/anchorpreference(key:value:transform:)) modifier, but first we need to create a [`PreferenceKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preferencekey) type to manage the collection.

```
struct AnchorsKey: PreferenceKey {
    // Each key is a row index. The corresponding value is the
    // .center anchor of that row.
    typealias Value = [Int: Anchor<CGPoint>]

    static var defaultValue: Value { [:] }

    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value.merge(nextValue()) { $1 }
    }
}
```

To turn an `Anchor<CGPoint>` into an actual `CGPoint`, we need a [`GeometryProxy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryproxy#). Assuming we have a proxy, we want to pick the row with the smallest y coordinate from those rows with a y coordinate of at least zero.

```
private func topRow(of anchors: AnchorsKey.Value, in proxy: GeometryProxy) -> Int? {
    var yBest = CGFloat.infinity
    var answer: Int? = nil
    for (row, anchor) in anchors {
        let y = proxy[anchor].y
        guard y >= 0, y < yBest else { continue }
        answer = row
        yBest = y
    }
    return answer
}
```

Now we need to wrap a [`GeometryReader`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader#) around the `ScrollView` to get a `GeometryProxy`, and use a [`.overlayPreferenceValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/overlaypreferencevalue(_:alignment:_:)) modifier inside the `GeometryReader` to get access to the collected `Anchor`s.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let myArray: [Int] = [Int](1...100)
    @State private var myRowNumber: Int = 50

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack{
                        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                            ForEach(myArray, id: \.self) { index in
                                Text("Row \(index)").id(index).font(.title)
                                    .anchorPreference(
                                        key: AnchorsKey.self,
                                        value: .center
                                    ) { [index: $0] }
                            }
                            .onAppear {
                                proxy.scrollTo(50, anchor: .top)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .overlayPreferenceValue(AnchorsKey.self) { anchors in
                    let i = topRow(of: anchors, in: proxy) ?? -1
                    Color.clear
                        .navigationTitle("Current row = \(i)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rob.  That works a treat!  As a relative newbie I would never have got there on my own.  PreferenceKeys are completely new to me so I'm going to have to get my head around them.  Thanks again for taking the time to answer

Comment: [The SwiftUI Lab](https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/) has a good sequence of articles about the SwiftUI preference system.

Comment: You can also track bottom visible row with `.scrollPosition(id: $scrolledID, anchor: .bottom)`